# Adjust window end position?

Tags: toyota, power-windows

I have a Toyota Yaris Verso (2000) and one of the screws holding the driver-side window fell out. As a result, the scissor mechanism of the motorized window adjuster was bent slightly before I was able to put the screw back.

Now it's working again, except that when closing the windows, it will travel all the way up, but then pull back 10cm. My suspicion is that this is a safety feature of the window adjuster.

Does anybody know what makes the motor stop, and possibly pull back? How does it know that the window is fully closed (so it stops but doesn't pull back), versus stopping and pulling back?

In the meantime, I've found the following information in the repair manual ("HOW TO RESET POWER WINDOW MOTOR"):

1. Remove the power window motor (Hint: Place the matchmarks on the power window motor and window regulator gear).
2. Connect the power window motor and power window switch to wire harness of the vehicle
3. Turn the ignition switch ON and operate the power window switch to idle the power window motor in UP side direction for more than 6 rotations or less than 10 rotates (4 seconds or more).
4. Assemble the power window motor and regulator. (Hint: - Install the motor when the regulator arm is below the middle point. - Align the matchmarks on the power window motor and window regulator gear.)
5. Assemble the power window regulator and door glass. (Hint: - Never rotate the motor to the down direction until the completion of the window glass installation.)
6. Connect power window switch to wire harness and turn the ignition switch ON.
7. Repeat UP and DOWN operation several times manually.
8. Check if AUTO UP -> AUTO DOWN operates in automatic operation.

Do I really need to disassemble everything just to reset the jam protection?? And in point 3, what exactly do I need to do? It says "> 6 rotations" OR "< 10 rotations" (>4s). That doesn't make sense - this means I can do whatever I want as long as it takes >4s.

And what "matchmarks" are they talking about?

Comment: I had to hold my auto down/up button down/up for 2 seconds after hitting the bottom/top to reset to auto up/down.

Comment: Procedure also works for 2003 Corolla Verso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, as the reset procedure requires the motor to turn freely through between 6 and 10 revolutions - without being connected to the window mechanism etc. you prehaps don't need to remove it from the door, but you will need to ensure it is disconnected from the mechanism, and this could be easiest if it is removed entirely. You will also be able to count revolutions etc.

Point 3 is very specific. You need to let it turn between 6 and 10 rotations - which should be 4 or more seconds. I would assume from the instructions that you should **not** let it turn more than 10 revolutions.

The marks mentioned are for your benefit. Before removing, draw on marks to show exactly where the moving parts are relative to each other and to the door. This way you will be able to make sure the motor is back in the correct orientation, and that the regulator and mechanism are in the correct position.

Comment: Thanks - I performed all the steps, let it turn 9 times, and it's now working as it should.

Comment: Tried this on my 2001 Toyota Spacio (Corolla) and it worked a treat. Fantastic !!!! Thanks very much.